# Issue with using a boolean in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a character controller and am trying to prevent the player from being able to dash forward whilst they are currently in a crouched position. I use booleans everywhere so I cannot figure out why the boolean for this doesn't work.

```
bool canDash = true;
bool isCrouching = false;
bool isCeilingAbove; // this uses a Physics.CheckSphere and GameObject

void Update()
{
    dashCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (isCeilingAbove)
    {
        isCrouching = false;
    }
    else
    {
        cc.height = Mathf.Lerp(startHeight, crouchHeight, currentCrouchAmount);
        cc.center = Vector3.Lerp(startCenter, crouchCenter, currentCrouchAmount);

        float crouchTargetValue = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) ? 1f : 0f;

        currentCrouchAmount = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentCrouchAmount, crouchTargetValue, ref currentCrouchVelocity, 0.25f);

        isCrouching = !isCrouching;
    }

    if (!isCrouching)
    {
        canDash = true;
    }

    if (canDash)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V))
        {
            if (dashCooldown <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Dash());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any booleans inside my IEnumerator itself and these are all the references I have to both the isCrouching & canDash booleans.

If I use basic crouch code like the one below, my canDash bool works. So I know that my code is fine, it's just I don't know how to implement that bool in my real code above.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
{
    cc.height = crouchHeight;
    cc.center = crouchCenter;
    isCrouching = true;
    canDash = false;
}
else
{
    cc.height = startHeight;
    cc.center = startCenter;
    isCrouching = false;
    canDash = true;
}
```

Comment: id say this issue was this  isCrouching = !isCrouching; as it means every itteration its false or true changes.  You want it just set to true here

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was actually one of the first things I tried to do, but then I cannot dash whilst crouched or standing up

Comment: I actually had no idea that you could attach a Input.GetKey to a bool like that, so that is great info thanks. Is there any difference between isCrouching = !isCrouching here and your suggestion? But this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isCrouching = !isCrouching;
```

alternates the state each frame forth and back. you should probably rather simply use

```
isCrouching = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
```

And actually `canDash` seems also quite redundant, why not simply check for `if(!isCrouching)`

I would probably rather have something like e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    dashCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

    // so if there is a ceiling and you are currently couching than you stay crouching
    // otherwise you directly take the key pressed state
    isCrouching = isCeilingAbove && isCrouching ? true : Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);

    var crouchTargetValue = isCrouching ? 1f : 0f;

    currentCrouchAmount = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentCrouchAmount, crouchTargetValue, ref currentCrouchVelocity, 0.25f);

    cc.height = Mathf.Lerp(startHeight, crouchHeight, currentCrouchAmount);
    cc.center = Vector3.Lerp(startCenter, crouchCenter, currentCrouchAmount);

    // I would even limit the dash to only work if fully standing
    if (Mathf.Approximately(currentCrouchAmount, 0f) && dashCooldown <= 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Dash());
    }
}
```

might then introduce another flag `isDashing` which is `true` as long as your `Dash` coroutine is running and prevent crouching until it is finished. Then you wouldn't even need the `dashCooldown` but could simply check for `if(!isDashing)`

Comment: Yeah I managed to fix it simply undoing my code that I previously had which was if (!isCrouching) and then do my dash, but the change that made all of this work was replacing my isCrouching bool inside my crouch code with: isCrouching = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl); which helped a lot. Thanks for the explanation